# sed retrieve part of line

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have lines of code that look like this:

`hi:12345:234` (second line)

How do I write a line of code using the sed command that only prints out the 2nd item in the second line?

My current command looks like this:

`sed -n '2p' file` which gets the second line, but I don't know what regex to use to match only the 2nd item '12345' and combine with my current command

Comment: You can do this: `awk -F: '(FNR==2){print $2}'` or this `sed -n "2{s/.*:\([^:]\+\):.*/\1/;p;q}"`

Comment: `sed -n '2{s/[^:]*://; s/:.*//p; q}'`

Answer (score 4):

Could you please try following, written and tested with shown samples in GNU `sed`.

```
sed -n '2s/\([^:]*\):\([^:]*\).*/\2/p' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Using `-n` option of `sed` will stop the printing for all the lines and printing will happen only for those lines where we are explicitly mentioning `p` option to print(later in code). Then mentioning `2s` means perform substitution on 2nd line only. Then using regex and `sed`'s capability to store matched regex into a temp buffer by which values can be retrieved later by numbering `1,2...and so on`. Regex is basically catching 1st part which comes before first occurrence of `:` and then 2nd part after first occurrence of `:` to till 2nd occurrence of `:` as per OP's request. So while doing substitution mentioning `/2` will replace whole line with 2nd value stored in buffer as per request, then mentioning `p` will print that part only in 2nd line.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of solutions:

```
echo "hi:12345:234" | sed -n '2s/.*:\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/p'
echo "hi:12345:234" | sed -n '2{s/^[^:]*://; s/:.*//p; q}'
echo "hi:12345:234" | awk -F':' 'FNR==2{print $2}'
```

All display `12345`.

`sed -n '2s/.*:\([0-9]*\):.*/\1/p'` only displays the captured value thanks to `-n` and `p` option/flag. It matches a whole string capturing digits between two colons, `\1` only keeps the capture.

The `sed -n '2{s/^[^:]*://;s/:.*//p;q}'` removes all from start till first `:`, all from the second to end, and then quits (`q`) so if your file is big, it will be processed quicker.

`awk -F':' 'FNR==2{print $2}'` splits the second line with a colon and fetches the second item.